# Есть ли ошибка в использовании деепричастного оборота?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, деепричастный-оборот

Правильно ли составлено это предложение? Есть ли ошибка в использовании деепричастного оборота?

"Перенеся серьёзную операцию, солдат был спасён".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложение составлено неправильно.

Сказуемое выражено конструкцией с кратким страдательным причастием (***был спасён** [кем-то]*), то есть подлежащее (***солдат***) по сути не является субъектом, не выполняет действия. А если нет действия, то не может быть и добавочного, выраженного деепричастием.

Аналогичный пример ошибки: *Перейдя дорогу не по правилам, я был оштрафован.*
Исправление: *Перейдя дорогу не по правилам, я заплатил штраф.*

[**Ошибки при использовании деепричастного оборота**](https://grammatika-rus.ru/oshibki-pri-ispolzovanii-deeprichastnogo-oborota/)

> Следует помнить, что **действие, выражаемое деепричастием, может относиться только к действующему подлежащему**. Действующее лицо  должно быть одно и то же – и для глагола, и для деепричастия.
> <...>
> – По указанной выше причине **не допускается использование деепричастия в пассивных (страдательных) конструкциях**, то есть в тех предложениях, где подлежащее указывает не на реальный субъект (он обычно выражен дополнением в творительном падеже), а объект действия. Ошибка: *Предупреждая образование пробки из-за снегопада, дорога очищается спецтехникой.* Исправление: *Предупреждая образование пробки из-за снегопада, спецтехника очищает дорогу.*

[**Ошибка в построении предложения с деепричастным оборотом**](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/rus_sprav?ajax=1&id=238&print=true&svg=0&num=true)

> Если сказуемое выражено **кратким причастием**, значит, подлежащее само не выполняет действие, с ним что-то делают. При такой форме сказуемого деепричастия не может быть.